# Display radio values on type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function() {
  var x = $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
  $("#gender-text").text($(this).val(x));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" >Male</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender: </label>
  <h5 id="gender-text"></h5>
</div>
```

In the above code, how do I display the selected radio values on type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `keyup` event over the `document` you should listen to the `change` event of your `radio` buttons.

- You need to use `$('input[name="gender"]')` to target your radio
  buttons, your selector is wrong because `'form input[type=radio]'` implies that your radio buttons are under a `form`, which is wrong.
- And instead of setting `$(this).val(x)` to the `display` element,
  just use `x` as it holds the `value` of the selected radio button, because `$(this)` in your code refers to `document` so your actual code will throw an error.

This is how should be your code:

```
$('input[name="gender"]').on('change', function() {
  var x = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
  $("#gender-text").text(x);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('input[name="gender"]').on('change', function() {
  var x = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
  $("#gender-text").text(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" >Male</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender: </label>
  <h5 id="gender-text"></h5>
</div>
```

Comment: With `change` event you changed functionality of OP question.

Comment: Really?! How is that? No, **I just changed the way of doing it** and I used the correct way to achieve the OP functionality.

Comment: Thankful for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

There is few problems.

1. Your `$(this).val(x)` sets value to `$(document)` and returns object, so not valid.
2. You are selecting `form`, but there is no such element in your DOM

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function() {
  var x = $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
  $("#gender-text").text(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>
    Male
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/>
    Female
  </label>
</form>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender: </label>
  <h5 id="gender-text"></h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two mistake here:

**One** You selecting like `$('form input[type=radio]:checked')` this way but no `form` element in your given DOM structure. So your selection should `$('input[type=radio]:checked')`.

**Another** point is no event will be bind on radio element `keyup` You should write `click` or `change` event here like following:

```
$(document).on('change', function() {
  var x = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
  $("#gender-text").text(x);
});
```

You also typed like `$("#gender-text").text($(this).val(x));` so meaning to `$(this).val(x)` this part. It should `$("#gender-text").text(x);`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" >Male</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender: </label>
  <h5 id="gender-text"></h5>
</div>

<script>
$(document).on('change', function() {
  var x = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
  $("#gender-text").text(x);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```